# Generic method arguments - Java

Tags: java, generics, collections, generic-collections

I have two almost identical methods, but I'm trying to avoid code duplication.

Each of them takes a unique object as arguments and finds out the highest value from it.

Here's an example:

```
public Integer getHighestIndexValue(List<ObjectA> list) {
    int highestValue;
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (ObjectA a: list) {
        indexes.add(Integer.parseInt(a.getA()));
    }
    highestValue = Collections.max(indexes);

    return highestValue;

}
```

Or:

```
public Integer getHighestIndexValue(List<ObjectB> list) {
    int highestValue;
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (ObjectB b: list) {
        indexes.add(Integer.parseInt(b.getB()));
    }
    highestValue = Collections.max(indexes);

    return highestValue;

}
```

How do I combine these two using generic parameters?

I tried creating a `BaseClass` that contains these two classes and extended it in the method signature. Still it requires casting.

```
public <T extends BaseClass> Integer getHighestIndexValue(List<T> objectList) {
    int highestValue;
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (T objects: objectList) {
        indexes.add(Integer.parseInt(objects.getAorB())); ------ this line needs casting
    }
    highestValue = Collections.max(indexes);

    return highestValue;

}
```

I have used Generics before but not generics parameters yet.

Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: I want to THANK all you guys for the response.I have to select this one as the best answer since IT WORKED LIKE A CHARM with minimal effort.. :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Can `getA` and `getB` be combined into a single interface method?

For example:

```
interface ProvidesIndex {
  Integer getIndex();
}
```

Now, you can simply call `getIndex`, and your method signature will be:

```
public Integer getHighestIndexValue(List<? extends ProvidesIndex> list)
```

As a side note, if you define your interface to extend `Comparable<ProvidesIndex>` i.e.:

```
interface ProvidesIndex extends Comparable<ProvidesIndex>
```

Then you can use `Collections.max` directly on the initial list:

```
List<ProvidesIndex> list = new ArrayList<ProvidesIndex>();
list.add(new ObjectA());
list.add(new ObjectB());
Integer max = Collections.max(list).getIndex();
```

Comment: Agreed; Because the method names are different, the use of generics won't solve your problem.  ObjectA and ObjectB need to have some common interface.

Comment: Roman, your note about Comparable was ok, add Comparator also and it is complete...

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the answer by Raman :

```
public Integer getHighestIndexValue(List<? extends CommonInterface> list) {
    int highestValue;
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (CommonInterface a: list) {
        indexes.add(Integer.parseInt(a. getIndex()));
    }

    highestValue = Collections.max(indexes);

    return highestValue;
}
```

Comment: Or better still <? extends CommonInterface>

Answer (score 3):

[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/OrderingExplained) has an elegant solution to this:

```
//general purpose function to get A, can be used in transform(), etc
private static final Function<ObjectA, Integer> GET_A = new Function<>() {
     @Override
     public Integer apply(ObjectA a) {
         return a.getA();
     }
}

Integer highestIndex = Collections.max(Collections2.transform(list, GET_A));
```

Or, if you need the element with the highest index,

```
ObjectA highest = Ordering.natural().onResultOf(GET_A).max(list);
```

Then to extend this to `ObjectB` you just need to implement a `GET_B` function.

Going back to your helper method (which is basically irrelevant now that you have a one-liner):

```
public <T> Integer getHighestIndex(List<? extends T> list, Function<? super T, Integer> indexPlucker) {
    return Collections.max(Collections2.transform(list, indexPlucker));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one Java command. Here is both Java 5 and a much more compact Java 8:

```
public static class ObjectA {
    public String getA() { return "1"; /* test */ }
}

public static class ObjectB {
    public String getB() { return "1"; /* test */ }
}

// Java 5+ versions

public static void sampleA7(List<ObjectA> list) {
    int maxValue = Integer.parseInt(Collections.max(list, new Comparator<ObjectA>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ObjectA a, ObjectA b) {
            return Integer.parseInt(a.getA()) - Integer.parseInt(b.getA());
        }
    }).getA());
}

public static void sampleB7(List<ObjectB> list) {
    int maxValue = Integer.parseInt(Collections.max(list, new Comparator<ObjectB>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ObjectB a, ObjectB b) {
            return Integer.parseInt(a.getB()) - Integer.parseInt(b.getB());
        }
    }).getB());
}

// Java 8+ versions

public static void sampleA8(List<ObjectA> list) {
    Optional<Integer> maxValue = list.stream().map(a -> Integer.parseInt(a.getA())).max((a, b) -> a - b);
}

public static void sampleB8(List<ObjectB> list) {
    Optional<Integer> maxValue = list.stream().map(a -> Integer.parseInt(a.getB())).max((a, b) -> a - b);
}
```

Comment: idea (with Comparator) is good, implementation is not, return max object not int, but then it is http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection, java.util.Comparator)

Comment: Do not use `Integer.parseInt(a.getB()) - Integer.parseInt(b.getB())`, but http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int, int) I think that OP's index is not what you think it is...

Comment: @Betista you are right, the index is a variable in both Object A and Object B. It could be like  anywhere from 1 - 400 passed by user through UI

Comment: betlista, fixed so it returns value. Java 8 version is much cleaner if you can use Java 8.

Comment: @user2684301 sorry, i am stuck with java 6

Answer (score 1):

it's probably not a good idea, if you want to make this code generic, to use an ArrayList of Integers to do the actual comparison. What if one of the objects is a Long, bigger than your max integer? Instead, your objects must be comparable somehow, so you can find the "maximum" (what's the maximum of a set of strings?)

So I'd try an approach like this

```
import java.util.List;

public abstract class MathMax<E> {
    public abstract boolean isGreaterThan(E x1, E x2);
    public E getHighestIndexValue(List<E> list){
        E highestValue = null;
        for (E a: list) {
            if (isGreaterThan(a,highestValue)){
                highestValue = a;
            }
        }
        return highestValue;
    }
}
```

and

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MathMaxA extends MathMax<ObjectA> {

    @Override
    public boolean isGreaterThan(ObjectA x1, ObjectA x2) {
        // do your comparison here, careful with null values
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MathMaxA m = new MathMaxA();
        List<ObjectA> list = new ArrayList<ObjectA>();
        System.out.println(m.getHighestIndexValue(list));
    }
}
```